# Loop for com comando isinstance() não funciona como esperado

Tags: python, python-3.x

Na primeira vez que printei a variável "b", esperava que aparecesse o número 6, porém é retornado um 0. No entanto, fora da função ele funciona perfeitamente. Como fazer com que esse código específico funcione dentro de uma função?

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'b']
b = 0


def how_many_integers(aa, bb):
    for i in aa:
        if isinstance(i, int):
            bb += 1


how_many_integers(a, b)
print(b) # Retorna 0

for i in a:
    if isinstance(i, int):
        b += 1

print(b) # Retorna 6
```

Comment: Porque não dá para passar um inteiro em Python por referência. Então, quando você altera `bb` dentro da função, a variável `b` passada como argumento continua armazenando o valor 0. Uma solução possível, seria declarar b como uma lista, tipo `b = [0]` e dentro da função usar `bb[0] += 1`, funcionaria, mas a arquitetura continuaria horrível. Quer dizer, se uma função conta a quantidade de inteiros, essa quantidade tem que ser o valor de retorno dela e não a alteração de um dos seus argumentos.

Comment: A variável `bb` é um parâmetro da função, e qualquer modificação feita ali não altera o `b` que está fora da função - [veja aqui](/a/443427/112052) uma explicação mais detalhada. Sem função funciona porque vc está alterando a própria variável `b`. O mais simples é fazer a função retornar o contador `bb`: https://ideone.com/zgsbwS

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, ajudou muito!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para justificar esse comportamento será necessário comentar sobre objetos mutáveis e imutáveis. Em resumo, objetos mutáveis permitem que seu valor seja alterado, enquanto imutáveis não.

Seu objeto `b` é do tipo `int`, que é imutável e, portanto, não permite ter seu valor alterado. Mas como posso fazer `b += 1` então e incrementar o valor dele? O que acontece, na verdade, é a criação de um novo objeto do tipo `int` com o valor `b+1` e a sobrescrita do `b` original pelo novo objeto.

Então por que não funciona em um caso e em outro não?

Quando você passa o objeto para a função, toda essa operação irá ocorrer no objeto `bb`, que é o parâmetro da função, existindo apenas localmente. Quando você faz `print(b)`, você ainda estará exibindo o objeto original, sem alterações, por isso aparece o zero.

Quando você modifica diretamente esse objeto no escopo global, como fez no laço  `for`, você perde a referência do objeto original `b` e sempre terá uma "versão atualizada" e, por isso, é exibido o valor 6.

Como comentado, a solução mais simples é você fazer o devido retorno do contador na função:

```py
def how_many_integers(aa):
    bb = 0
    for i in aa:
        if isinstance(i, int):
            bb += 1
    return bb

b = how_many_integers(a)
print(b)  # 6
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação Woss!